# Get number of records by comparing the year value in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a list of people ID who has attended training from 2014 to 2018. I need to get details of number of people who has not attended training in 2017 and attended in 2018.

[image: img]

i filtered the year ("Start date") to 2017 and 2018. and used no of records to check how many people attended.

Now how do i get number of records from this list that who has attended training in 2018 and not in 2017?

i tried this in the calculation. but it shows Null value.

```
SUM(IF ISNULL(YEAR([Start Date])=2017) AND 
NOT ISNULL(YEAR([Start Date]) =2018) 
THEN
1
END)
```

[image: img2]

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Calculated Field (Check 2018):

   IF YEAR([Start date]) = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
2. Convert the Calculated Field to Discrete Dimension
3. Filter the sheet with only 1

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of users who attended in 2017 and another set who attended in 2018.
Create a combined set comparing 2017 and 2018. select option of 2018 except shared members (last one).